Pdf translations to japanese language is not working in Azure environment but working in local enviroment
I am generating the pdf report using puppeteer-sharp. I want to translate the pdf in multiple languages.I am able to translate the pdf in french, portuguese language but not for japanese and thai language.
For Japanese language, the translation of pdf is working fine in local environment but when I push this code Azure in production/UAT enviroment, pdf is not translated to japanese language.
public async Task<Models.File> GenerateDiagnosticReport(Diagnostic diagnostic,bool isImperial, bool showExposition, bool showConsistency,CultureInfo culture, bool showUserData)
{
    var html = await this.GetContent("Views/report.cshtml", new MobileReportViewModel(diagnostic, isImperial, showExposition, showConsistency,culture, showUserData));
    var pdf = await this.CreatePdf(html);

    var pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
    pdfStream.Write(pdf);
    pdfStream.Position = 0;
    return new Models.File
    {
        Content = pdfStream,
        ContentType = "application/pdf",
        Name = $"diagnostic.pdf"
    };
}

private async Task<byte[]> CreatePdf(string htmlContent)
 {
     await using var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
     {
         Headless = true,
         ExecutablePath = PuppeteerExtensions.ExecutablePath,
         Args = new string[] { "--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox" }
     });

     await using var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
     await page.EmulateMediaTypeAsync(MediaType.Screen);
     await page.SetContentAsync(htmlContent);

     return await page.PdfDataAsync(new PdfOptions
     {
         Format = PaperFormat.A4,
         PrintBackground = true
     });
 }


Below is the attached image of pdf which is not translated
Pdf not translated
I am expecting this
enter image description here
Note: I am using localization for language translation

Fonts not installed?

@Kamlesh Jangley Font may not be available in app service environment

@VivekVaibhavShandilya We are using base64 font in css file.

@KamleshJangley try installing Japanese and Thai fonts inside your azure app service.

if possible can you share your repo?

@VivekVaibhavShandilya Sorry, I can't share repo.

@VivekVaibhavShandilya I have installed the fonts in app service still facing same issue .

@KamleshJangley I think your issue is related to fonts you are using, may  be fonts are not supporting in Azure web app. I would suggest try using different fonts. As issue is related to only japanese and thai fonts.
